# How to modify the file content using sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

IP file - `1.txt`

```
$ cat 1.txt
'&1'
'&2'
'&3'
```

if I want the o/p as

```
:1
:2
:3
```

using sed, (or any command for that matter), how do I achieve?

Comment: what is the content of the file ?

Comment: so, you want to extract numbers from each line and while printing add a `:` before the number?

Comment: I/P
Monday {'&1', 'Morning', 'Breakfast'}
Tuesday {'&2', 'Noon', 'Lunch'}
Wednesday {'&3', 'Evening', 'Supper'}
Thursday {'&4', 'Night', 'Dinner'}

**O/P**
Monday {:1, 'Morning', 'Breakfast'}
Tuesday {:2, 'Noon', 'Lunch'}
Wednesday {:3, 'Evening', 'Supper'}
Thursday {:4, 'Night', 'Dinner'}

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40653910/edit) your question instead of adding comment.. see also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/'"^'"'|'"'$"'/,"");gsub(/&/,":")}1' input
:1
:2
:3
```

Here , `awk`'s `gsub` function is used to replace single quotes to blank and another gsub is used to replace `&` to `:`. `1` means,print in awk.

Comment: This works, Could you please explain how it works. Thanks in advance.
because, whatever the input I have shared, it's there in the middle of the line

Comment: @Guru24, in that case, you should have given a better input sample as it is easy to just assume that those are the only contents in the line.. see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: updated answer with some explanation. Agree with @Sundeep , need more clarity about input and expected output ,if you are not satisfied with this.

Comment: Agree. I will modify the I/p and expected o/p

Answer (score 0):

You can get your o/p by using below 2 commands.

--> sed -e '/1/b' -e '/2/b' -e '/3/b' -e d 1.txt
or
--> gsed '/1:2:3/!d' 1.txt

Answer (score 0):

Is this fine ?

```
sed -e 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\)[^0-9]*$/:\1/' 1.txt

:1
:2
:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat 1.txt 
Monday {'&1', 'Morning', 'Breakfast'}
Tuesday {'&2', 'Noon', 'Lunch'}
Wednesday {'&3', 'Evening', 'Supper'}
Thursday {'&4', 'Night', 'Dinner'}

$ sed -E 's/\x27&([0-9]+)\x27/:\1/' 1.txt 
Monday {:1, 'Morning', 'Breakfast'}
Tuesday {:2, 'Noon', 'Lunch'}
Wednesday {:3, 'Evening', 'Supper'}
Thursday {:4, 'Night', 'Dinner'}
```

- `\x27&` match single quote and `&` (See [ASCII set](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for reference)
- `([0-9]+)` capture digits for back-referencing
- `\x27` match single quote
- `:\1` replace matched pattern with `:` and captured digits
- Note: some `sed` versions use `-r` instead of `-E` for extended regex option